# "Word could not create the work file. Check the temp environment variable" error when previewing Microsoft Word documents

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, environment-variables

When **single-clicking** a `.doc`, `.docx` or `.rtf` file, or attempting to **double-click** any of the aforementioned files I get the error int the title.

What I already tried:

1. [Following this Microsoft article, and changing the registry.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2285187)
2. [Following this SU question and checking the my folder is **not ecrypted**](https://superuser.com/questions/650764/microsoft-word-suddenly-wont-save-files-word-could-not-create-the-work-file)
3. Uninstalling completely then re-installing Office.

None of these seem to work - and this error causes the entire explorer process to freeze sometimes, as well.

Comment: Have you tried a repair install of Office?

Comment: That's kind of a hail mary move, which I tried to no avail.

Comment: What version of Office? What OS? Have you run any disk scans? Malware scan? Virus scan? Is this computer logged into a domain?

Comment: If you're using Windows, start `cmd` and type `echo temp >%temp%\temp.txt`. If this runs without error and `type %temp%\temp.txt` shows `temp`, then there is nothing wrong with your `temp` directory and the message is misleading, so check your event logs for relevant errors. (On OSX use the equivalent `bash` commands.)

Comment: @CharlieRB no domain, ran a disk scan - all is well, antivirus runs constantly with no threats shown.

Comment: @AFH - all works with the temp vars. Which logs should I check? And where?

Comment: Try registering Word with Windows again. Run > `winword.exe /r`

Comment: @CharlieRB - Did that too, doesn't work.

Comment: Check Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer.

Comment: The logs don't show the error - not as Microsoft Office alerts or General Windows alerts, at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this [guide](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/word-could-not-create-work-file/) on *thewindowsclub* which sent me to the registry editor and ended up elucidating the issue for me.

It turned out that *if you have renamed your user account* at some point in the past, your **cache** and **cookies** folders may have the incorrect paths in the following location in the registry:

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

Changing these entries in the registry seems to have cleared up the issue entirely. The rest of that guide may help, too.

Comment: Everything in my registry is correct. Unfortunately this is not working for me.

Comment: Fixed it for me! Changed the value to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache`.